# Attaching to gdb interupts and won't continue the process

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb, embedded-linux

got some big real time project to deal with (multiple processes (IPCs), multi Everything in short).

My working on process is started as service on Linux. I have the root access.

**Here is the problem:**

I'm trying to attach to a running proc, tried starting it through/with gdb but the result is the same: it stops the executable once I "touched" it with gdb or sometimes it throws:

```
Program received signal SIGUSR1, User defined signal 1. [Switching to Thread 0x7f9fe869f700 (LWP 2638)]
```

of course from there nothing can be done.

Tried:

1. handle all nostop
2. attach to launched as service (daemon) or launched as regular proc
3. started from gdb
4. thought maybe forking/multi-threaded problem - implemented in the very beginning sleep for 10 seconds - attached to it with "continue"

Guys, all I want it is to debug, hit the breakpoints, etc.

Please help! Share ideas.

Editing actual commands:

1)  **gdb attach myProcId.** Then after reading symbols, I hit "c" which results:

Program received signal SIGUSR1, User defined signal 1.
[Switching to Thread 0x7f9fe869f700 (LWP 2638)]
0x00007f9fec09bf73 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6

2) If I make the first line 10 seconds sleep in the code, attaching to the process, hit "c", result: it runs, shows info threads, backtrace of main, but never hits the breakpoint (for sure the code runs there - I get logs and different behaviour if I change code there), meaning the process is stuck.

3) All other combinations like **gdb path/to/my/proc** args list,  then start. Where arg list played with different related options gdb gives us.

Maybe worth to mention: process network packets related, timers driven also. 
But for me the important thing is a current snapshot on break, i don't care what will happen to the system after timers expired.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Are you saying that after gdb has attached you can't simply type `continue` at the prompt?  You might also want to edit your question to show the precise command you use to attach.

Comment: What is the proc you're attaching to?  Provide commands you use to start it and how do you attach to it.

Comment: Debuggers and breakpoints do not mix well with multi-threading/muli-processing unless you can somehow *stop everything*.  I've learned to desk-check the code, and/or insert **printf()** (or **printk()** in the kernel) where necessary to obtain salient values or states.  If you do it right, you learn not to trust your assumptions.

Comment: @sawdust Sure thing, logs are good. Just sometimes it takes to long, adding 1 print, compile (in my case it takes 6 min), execute then u realize that you need to have the some other values and backtrace values. Meaning getting out, printing again, compiling .... iterative time consuming and frustrating process. Instead, of debugging, going forth and back, with all values (some of them editable) saves hours of "print" work.

Comment: Yes, the revise-compile-test cycle can be time consuming.  That's why I wrote that you have to work smarter, and review the code for flaws.  Then test your assumptions to ensure that you haven't found a corner case.  Go ahead & use breakpoints on a solitary program.  But if you have a process interacting with a remote processor that would revert to some recovery mode (i.e. if you cannot afford to disrupt other processes), then IMO the better choice is to use **printf()** s.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you are debugging a multiprocessing program, I think the underlying program you have is to set the breakpoint in the correct subprocess.

Try `break fork` and `set follow-fork-mode child/parent`. What you want to achieve is have gdb attached to the process that is running the code you want to debug.
Refer to this [link](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html).

Another thought is to generate a crash, since you can compile the programe. For example add a `int i = *(int*)NULL` and that will generate a core dump. You can then debug the core dump with `gdb <program> <core dump>`. You can refer to this [page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Core_dump) for how to configure core dump.